# Duvida JPA 2.1 e Hibernate 5.2

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Tenho algumas duvidas com JPA 2.1 e Hibernate 5.2.
A ultima versao do estandar JPA é a 2.1. Certo? 
É correto falar que posso implementar uma AP só com JPA sem hibernate?
Quais sao as funcionalidades de hibernate 5.2 que estao fora do estandar JPA 2.1? 
Hibernate 5.2 suporta NoSQL?
Quais sao as vantagem de utilizar JPA  frente ao hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você não precisa do Hibernate para usar JPA, mas vai precisar de outro framework ORM similiar ao Hibernate como o EclipseLink, TopLink, etc.

O framework é a implementação da especificação JPA, ou seja, a JPA é como se fosse uma interface e o framework a classe que implementa a interface. Então você sempre vai precisar de framework ORM para trabalhar com JPA.

A JPA 2.1 é a última versão da especificação JPA, embora o Hibernate mude constantemente de versão ele sempre segue as regras necessárias para trabalhar com a versão JPA 2.1. O que ele muda entre as versões são correções de bugs, melhorias de performance e outros recursos próprios do próprio framework que podem nem existir na JPA.

Sobre as vantagens entre Hibernate e JPA é que a JPA é uma especificação e qualquer framework que implemente a especificação está apto a ser usado por ela. Neste caso, se você usa JPA com Hibernate, amanhão poderá substituir o Hibernate pelo EclipseLink sem muito esforço. Vai precisar apenas mudar algumas instruções no arquivo de configuração da JPA. Caso trabalhe 100% com Hibernate, sem JPA, caso resolva amanhã mudar para o EclipseLink, vai precisar alterar a configuração do framework e também os métodos de escrita e leitura e também os mapeamentos das entidades. O esforço nessa troca seria muito alto.

O Hibernate tem um versão chamada, [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) que é utilizado para trabalhar com alguns bancos de dados não relacionais (NoSQL).